# Is it worth creating an interface for a trivial return type?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

Consider the following interfaces:

```
public interface IPlayerRepository
{
  IPlayerInfo GetPlayerInfo(int id);
}

public interface IPlayerInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
  public int GamesWon { get; set; }
}
```

and the associated implementations:

```
public class PlayerRepository : IPlayerRepository
{
  IPlayerInfo GetPlayerInfo(int id)
  {
    // read from external data store
    return new PlayerInfo();
  }
}

public class PlayerInfo : IPlayerInfo
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int GamesPlayed { get; set; }
  public int GamesWon { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any value in having the separate `IPlayerInfo` interface, given that the class only exists as a collection of properties to be returned by this method?  Would it be preferable to just have the `IPlayerRepository.GetPlayerInfo` method return a concrete `PlayerInfo` object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you think you can have more than one kind of `PlayerInfo` (which is likely to be the case if `PlayerInfo` is a class and not a struct), then yes. If it's something that'll probably never change, then probably not.

Answer (score 3):

If you plan on creating mockups for unit testing, this might be worthwhile. In this particular case, it might be worth mocking the `IPlayerRepository`, but probably not the `IPlayerInfo`.

Answer (score 1):

`PlayerInfo` is just a simple data-storage-structure, and does not have much of a contract to formalize in a form of an interface. I avoid creating interfaces for classes that don't really **DO** anything.

Answer (score 1):

It's not just whether you will ever have a different kind of an entity, but also whether it will need mocking during testing.

If your entity will never perform any business logic, I wouldn't bother, personally.

Answer (score 1):

IMO.  Don't try to write code for a type that you haven't thought of yet.  I find it's always easier to write code that makes sense, and isn't overly abstracted or overly complicated.  You can always refactor it when you get to the point where your requirements change and you have more than one type of PlayerInfo that will require a different implementation.